# Zoom in and out without the need for holding ctrl or alt key down

Tags: zooming

Zoom in and out without the need to hold down **crtl** key would make navigation much easier and faster.
It is really a question why **developers/UI/UX designers** of many of design softwares do not pay attention to this important fact that the user might do zoom in and out hundreds of times in a day and forcing him/her to hold down the **ctrl** or **alt** key all the time is tiresome and less productive.
Hope they understand this important fact and do accordingly to solve the problem like what **Inkscape** and **Gimp** have done to make it possible to choose the preferred settings.

**Question**
Is there a way one could achieve this in **adobe xd** or in **figma**? Tried **AutoHotKey** software to convert **mouse scroll** to **ctrl down + mouse scroll** but it skips some steps and moves the screen up and down between some steps.
Is there any **plugin** or any different approach to make it possible to **zoom** in and out without the need to keep **ctrl** or any other modifer key down?

*Appreciate your share of knowledge.*

Comment: This sounds like a rant. What are you asking? Right now it reads as if we would have to been involved in the decision making process for us to answer the question.

Comment: If you are asking how to do something with a specific piece of software then perhaps try [superuser](https://superuser.com/). Please ensure to read their posting guidelines before you ask a question.

Comment: @musefan That's right I mistakenly posted here again. Thanks for the help. Posted on super user now.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its about shortcuts

Answer (score 1):

Sharing my knowledge here:

Trackpad:

- Two finger pinch to zoom in and out (eg: Figma, Chrome)
- Two finger double tap to zoom in first. Repeat to zoom out (eg: Google Chrome)

Touch devices:

- Two finger pinch to zoom in and out (eg: Maps, Chrome)
- One finger double tap to zoom in. (eg: Maps)
- Two finger single tap to zoom out first.(eg: Maps)

How Figma deals with it:

- Understand from your description of the problem that holding down control and zooming is tedious.
- Figma has this clever list of shortcuts to make peoples life easier.

[image]

Gimp and Photoshop: Zoom tool itself:

- Use the zoom tool to zoom in and out instead of scrolling.

[image]

I don't think this helps a lot. But might help someone someday haha. Cheers :)